area of lune given some data
Please could anyone help with how to find the area described below?:
"Consider a large circle E with center N and a chord AB. And a point C in this circle, so that ABC forms an isosceles right triangle at C. Again, let us have a circumscribed circle F which passes through this triangle ABC centred at the midpoint M of AB. Find the portion area (shaded area) of circle F that extends outside circle E, knowing that the area of ​​the triangle is 8."
I managed to calculate some lengths in the diagram below but became stuck for ages...


Do you know how to calculate the area of the semicircle ACB and the sector $CADB$? Then $S_{ADBM}=S_{CADB}-S_{\Delta ACB}$ and shaded area$=\pi (2\sqrt 2)^2-S_{ADBM}-\text{semicircle}ACB$

From the text of the problem it looks like the radius of $E$ is undetermined, and also consequently the area. Are you sure the text is complete?


The required area $=$ area of semicircle $ABG-~$arc-area $ABD$.
Arc-area of $ABD=$ area of sector $ABD-$ area of triangle $ABC$.


Thank you @AngaeMT, I don't know how I missed final steps...

AngaeMT - the arc area is known as a circular segment.
